# ajax jquery checkbox first click not firing in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am using struts 1.1 in java which have action,form and bo.To be faster i also used ajax in my code.i successfully fetch data into grid using ajax.The next task is when a user click checkbox from a single row a new window will be opened.But the problem is that the checkbox action is not working at first click,it only works from second click in chrome.It smoothly works in IE and upper version of firefox.Note that i am using jquery 1.9.1 library.
Here is my Jsp code---------

```js
//This is checkbox calling function............

function openWinForChequeDetails(f){
      $(document).ready(function(){
    // $('.chk').val($(this).is(':checked'));

     //Attach button clicke event handler    
             $('.chk').change(function () {
     
              //Loop through each checkbox in table
               $("table tr td input[type=checkbox]");
                  //Check if checkbox nis checked or not
                      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                      //if checked then get the value
                          var v1 = $(this).parent().siblings('td').eq(1).text();
       var Asondate = document.postOutwardClearingChequesForm.asOnDate.value;
         var flg = 'Y';

     alert("CHeckbox==>"+flg);

 winURL="/mybank/chequeDetailsPostOutwardClearingCheques.do?batchNumber="+v1+"&docDate="+Asondate+"&flag="+flg;   
 winName = "PostOutwardClearingChequesDetails";
  winHeight = 380;
  winWidth = screen.availWidth - 15;
  winTop = ((screen.availHeight/2) - (winHeight / 6));

  winLeft = 0;
  winOpen = "";
  
  if(winOpen){
   if(winOpen.closed){
    winOpen = window.open(winURL, winName, "top=" + winTop + ",left=" + winLeft + ",width=" + winWidth + ",height=" + winHeight + ",resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,status=no,menubar=no")
   } else { 
    winOpen.close();
    winOpen = window.open(winURL, winName, "top=" + winTop + ",left=" + winLeft + ",width=" + winWidth + ",height=" + winHeight + ",resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,status=no,menubar=no")
   }
  } else {
   winOpen = window.open(winURL, winName, "top=" + winTop + ",left=" + winLeft + ",width=" + winWidth + ",height=" + winHeight + ",resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,status=no,menubar=no")
  }
  winOpen.focus();
 
   }   else{
    
   var flg='N' ;
   alert(flg);
   $.ajax({
   url:'/mybank/unChequeDetailsPostOutwardClearingCheques.do?batchNumber='+v1+'&docDate='+Asondate+'&flag='+flg,
            type:'post',  
            dataType: 'json'  
       
  }); 
    
    }Console.log("Quite Method"); 
    

     });
});
 }
```

```html
//This is Ajax Calling from gridview.................. 

var rowNew= $('<td align="center" class="lbl-08" width="9%"></td>').html('<input type="checkbox"  onclick="openWinForChequeDetails(postOutwardClearingChequesForm)" class="chk" value="Y" indexed="true" />').appendTo(tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS function to this. You do not need `$(document).ready` or `$('.chk').change` in this scenario as you have already called the function directly in the `onclick` event.

```
//This is checkbox calling function............

function openWinForChequeDetails(f, elem){
      //Loop through each checkbox in table

                  //Check if checkbox is checked or not
                      if ($(elem).is(':checked')) {
                      //if checked then get the value
                          var v1 = $(elem).parent().siblings('td').eq(1).text();
                         var Asondate = document.postOutwardClearingChequesForm.asOnDate.value;
                     var flg = 'Y';

                alert("CHeckbox==>"+flg);

    winURL="/mybank/chequeDetailsPostOutwardClearingCheques.do?batchNumber="+v1+"&docDate="+Asondate+"&flag="+flg;          
    winName = "PostOutwardClearingChequesDetails";
        winHeight = 380;
        winWidth = screen.availWidth - 15;
        winTop = ((screen.availHeight/2) - (winHeight / 6));

        winLeft = 0;
        winOpen = "";

        if(winOpen){
            if(winOpen.closed){
                winOpen = window.open(winURL, winName, "top=" + winTop + ",left=" + winLeft + ",width=" + winWidth + ",height=" + winHeight + ",resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,status=no,menubar=no")
            } else { 
                winOpen.close();
                winOpen = window.open(winURL, winName, "top=" + winTop + ",left=" + winLeft + ",width=" + winWidth + ",height=" + winHeight + ",resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,status=no,menubar=no")
            }
        } else {
            winOpen = window.open(winURL, winName, "top=" + winTop + ",left=" + winLeft + ",width=" + winWidth + ",height=" + winHeight + ",resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,status=no,menubar=no")
        }
        winOpen.focus();

         }   else{

            var flg='N' ;
            alert(flg);
            $.ajax({
            url:'/mybank/unChequeDetailsPostOutwardClearingCheques.do?batchNumber='+v1+'&docDate='+Asondate+'&flag='+flg,
            type:'post',  
            dataType: 'json'  

        }); 

                }Console.log("Quite Method"); 



    }
```

And your Ajax call:

```
//This is Ajax Calling from gridview..................  

var rowNew= $('<td align="center" class="lbl-08" width="9%"></td>').html('<input type="checkbox"  onclick="openWinForChequeDetails(postOutwardClearingChequesForm, this)" class="chk" value="Y" indexed="true" />').appendTo(tr);
```